# Don't think too hard or your brain will melt

Tags: riddle, visual

Can you guess the word from the following images?

[image: Birthday Surprise]

[image: Diver]

[image: Country]

[image: Band]

[image: Wagon]

[image: Vampire Kryptonite]

Comment: It's the easy ones that give me nightmares...

Comment: That's a stake?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would go with

> Cheese

as in

> [Cheese cake](https://www.thecheesecakefactory.com/assets/images/Menu-Import/CCF_FreshStrawberryCheesecake.jpg)
>  [Cheese board](http://www.castellocheese.com/optimized/maximum/siteassets/the-journal/global/how-to--guides/how-to-style-a-cheese-board-3.jpg) thank you BrentHackers for this.
>  [Cottage Cheese](http://www.healthline.com/hlcmsresource/images/topic_centers/Food-Nutrition/642x361-Is_Cottage_Cheese_Good_For_You.jpg)
>  [Cheese Strings](https://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/mt/2014/11/shutterstock_219722968/lead_large.jpg?1430149773)
>  [Cheese wagon](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cheese%20wagon) or [Cheese wheel](https://www.displayfakefoods.com/store/pc/catalog/5578-lg.jpg) as rand al'thor suggests
>  [Cheese Steak](https://www.chowhound.com/blog-media/2014/08/philly_cheesesteak_carousel.jpg)

Bonus for the title

> [Melted cheese](http://i.huffpost.com/gen/1765360/images/o-MELTING-CHEESE-facebook.jpg)

Comment: Wheel, not wagon, I think.

Comment: Definitely a "******Wheel" or "Wheel of ******" +1 @Randal'thor

Comment: Thank you both. I will give each of you 16.6% of the the fake internet points I get for this one.

Comment: 16.6?  I'll take it!   ...That last link made me hungry...

Comment: I can vouch for those Philly Cheese Steaks - but that image is not the same stake :(

Comment: Correct, great answer!

Comment: Everyone forgot [Brain ******](https://www.google.com/search?q=brain+cheese)!

Answer (score 2):

we got:

> Happy birthday cake
>  swimming pool
>  country side house
>  Musical Instruments
>  Wheel
>  Dagger

So I think the answer is

> Music or Song

Because of:

> A lot of Birthday songs
>  a famous [Swimming pool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B5YNiCfWC3A) song
>  country music
>  A picture of Musical instrument
>  [Wheel of musical impressions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2OFKM2G-dE8)
>  And finally a classical song by Joan Baez called Silver dagger

As four the title:

> Some songs can melt your heart

Comment: Good answer but wrong. :)